# Why sprockets can't load .src extention files, Sprockets::ContentTypeMismatch error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

in a rails 4 project, i have a index.js file and data.src.js file, if i put this line in index.js

`//= require data.src`

i will get a Sprockets::ContentTypeMismatch error, there are two ways to fix this, one is rename data.src.js to data.js, then `//require data`, second one is `//= require data.src.js`

however, these lines works, they all have extensions

`//= require bootstrap-datepicker.zh-CN`
`//= require jquery.SuperSlide.2.1.1`
`//= require unslider.min`
`//= require jquery.slides.fix`